# I want to Create a receipt – order number, customer, list of items, prices and date. in MySQL

Tags: mysql

[image]

I want output in such a way that for customer Jim Wilson, the product name should be in the same box.

Comment: I have used Group by Customer id, but all product name is not displayed. I want to show all products

Comment: Please paste your SELECT statement so we can copy it

Comment: Select O.Order_Id, customer, O.Product_Name, (P.Amount), O.Order_Date From payments P 
join orders O  on O.Customer_ID = P.Customer_ID
join customer C on C.Customer_Id = O.Customer_ID @RodrigoKravetz

Comment: To put in same "box" use CONCAT: `CONCAT(customer, ' ',O.Product_NAME) AS customerAndProduct`. But I don't understand why you need to join everything, if a payment is related to a client, and not to an order.

Comment: Same box as what?

Comment: for example for the customer Jim Wilson, the product name should include, Blackberries, C4, Fuji apples in the same box as the product name. Amount - 358.60 same

Comment: I don't want customer column values should be repeated. And all the product names should be displayed.

Comment: Which orderid would you like?

Comment: any order id, i just want product name in same column as mentioned above